# Visual studio code: Debug console does not print values on flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Hi recently I have had a problem with the visual studio code console and the flutter prints only work for a moment and after the prints are shown in the console. Could someone help me what it is? It only works for a moment when the project just starts, in the image you can see how the prints appear as I/flutter (20702) and then they stop appearing and only the Getx package information appears. Thank you

[image]

```
{
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
},
"[dart]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.rulers": [
        80
    ],
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
},
"dart.analyzerPath": null,
"dart.onlyAnalyzeProjectsWithOpenFiles": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"files.associations": {
    "*.dart": "dart"
},
"[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
},
"[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
},
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
"errorLens.excludeBySource": [
    "dart(file_names)",
    "dart(invalid_assignment)",
    "dart(unnecessary_cast)",
    "dart(invalid_use_of_protected_member)"
],
"easycode.userEmail": "hortigadoz@gmail.com",
"npm.keybindingsChangedWarningShown": true,
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"dart.lineLength": 150,
"formatAll.includeFileExtensions": [
    ".dart",
],
"formatAll.excludeFolders": [
    "node_modules",
    "out",
    ".vscode-test",
    ".dart_tool",
    "lib/brick",
    "media"
],
"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": true,
"[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "fabianlauer.vs-code-xml-format"
},
"editor.maxTokenizationLineLength": 90000,
```

}